# What is the cuneiform glyph for peace?

Tags: cuneiform, sumerian, unicode

Is there such a thing as a symbol or glyph for "peace" in cuneiform script.

If it does exist, does it exist in the [unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuneiform_(Unicode_block))?

Comment: Cuneiform is a writing system, not a language. It almost makes sense to ask "What is the Ket word for 'peace'?", meaning "most closely translates". What is the "Latin alphabet" word for peace?

Comment: @user6726 cuneiform has a pretty significant number of logograms, so the question is a lot more like "what is the Chinese character for 'peace'", than it is any of the questions you suggest. The question is well-posed, but almost certainly off-topic for this site

Answer (score 2):

One option is  SILIM. I don't know about the Sumerian side of things, but in Akkadian it can be used as a logogram for [salīmu(m)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sal%C4%ABmum#Akkadian) 'peace'.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkCXs.jpg) is the entry in Labat's *Manuel d'épigraphie Akkadienne*, as that's what I have on hand. The image on the far left is the Sumerian pictograph (the oldest attested form), the ones in the second column other Sumerian versions. Row A are Assyrian forms, row B Babylonian, in chronological order (Old, Middle, Neo-). The final column (the first of the second page) is the "traditional" Neo-Assyrian citation form.

Comment: In Sumerian SILIM is more about health and completeness than peace, usually glossed with Akkadian _šalāmum_.